# PHP error 401 al usarl cURL para consumo de Api Google Cloud

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-platform

Tengo que consumir una de las api de Google Cloud Platform desde PHP
En el tutorial tengo este ejemplo

```
curl -X GET \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \   "https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/datasets/DATASET_ID/dicomStores/DICOM_STORE_ID/dicomWeb/instances"
```

Tengo un token de acceso OAuth tipo JSON de este estilo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código PHP es el siguiente

```
<?php
    $key = file_get_contents('key.json');
    $url = 'https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/datasets/DATASET_ID/dicomStores/DICOM_STORE_ID/dicomWeb/instances';
    $headers = ['"Authorization: Bearer'.$key.'"'];
    // open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  http_build_query($headers) );
    // execute
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
    // close connection
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

El error que recibo es ["code":401,status: UNAUTHENTICATED ]

Comment: ¿Dónde estás recibiendo el mensaje de error? Convendría quizá revisar el log de errores para tener una descripción más amplia del motivo del error. Lo cierto es que por algún motivo no está reconociendo las credenciales que estás pasando en la petición cURL. ¿Tienes esa API activada en la consola de Google? ¿El dominio desde el que haces la petición está autorizado?

Comment: El mensaje lo recibo en la respuesta de curl_exec($ch). 
Esta testeado por otro metodo y funciona desde esta IP y con esas credenciales. Supongo que el error esta en como se envían las credenciales, no se si es correcto hacerlo de la manera que lo hago

Comment: Te falta un espacio en blanco entre `Bearer` y `$key`. De todos modos, usa una sintaxis lo más simple posible, puedes usar comillas dobles y meter dentro las variables, de ese modo evitas concatenaciones que llevan a confusión y considera poner siempre los encabezados del tipo de contenido. Por ejemplo: `$auth = "Authorization: Bearer $key";
$headers=array('Content-Type: application/json' , $auth);`